# Unzipping NSData with ZipArchive

Tags: ios, unzip, php-ziparchive

I am using ZipArchive and am reading data in from a device. What I want to do is take the data from the device and unzip it. The only examples I can find are taking the data, writing it to a file on the iOS device, and reading (unzipping) it back again...

This is the code (not working) that I have writing it to disk...

```
    // Read the data in...
if ((recvStringLen = recvfrom(connectSock, recvString, 1025, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&broadcastAddr, &recvStringLen)) < 0) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Unable to receive user perms message.");
    [self showTimeoutError];
    return -1;
}

// get the file size...
unsigned int fileSize = (( recvString[16] << 24 ) & 0xff000000) |
                        (( recvString[17] << 16 ) & 0xff0000) |
                        (( recvString[18] << 8 ) & 0xff00 ) |
                        ( recvString[19] & 0xff );

NSLog(@"fileSize: %i", fileSize);

recvString[20+fileSize] = '\0'; // terminate the string...

// convert the char data to a string
NSString *stringData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", &recvString[20]] autorelease];
NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:stringData length:fileSize] autorelease];

// write the data...
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userinfo.zip"];
[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];

// exist?
BOOL zipExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appFile];

NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userinfo.zip"];

NSString *output = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userinfo.dat"];

ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

// unzip it...
BOOL success = [za UnzipOpenFile:zipFilePath];
if( success ) {
    BOOL outSuccess = [za UnzipFileTo:output overWrite:YES];
    if( outSuccess != NO ) {
        NSLog(@"success");
    }

    [za UnzipCloseFile];
}

[za release];

BOOL datExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:output];
```

When it gets to 'success', it is always NO... even though 'zipExists' is YES.

The two issues I have:
1. The I haven't successfully written the data to disk, read it back, and unzipped it.
2. I would rather just unzip the data (NSData) instead of going thru writing it to disk and reading it back again...

I searched before posting, but was unable to find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Skip creating a NSString - that is your problem (or one of them). Create the data object from recvString directly. Think about what happens using %s if the data has a null byte.

Comment: Thank you. I made the change... still doesn't work. Is there a way to unzip the data without writing it to disk first?